# Building supply depots - mission

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-2

From the beginning of the game there is a mandatory task which says: Build 3 new supply depots. I must say that it is very hard to complete for my team. **My question: Do supply depots that we have from the begin of our game counts for this mission?** Because we bought improvement and from start we have 2 supply depots.

Comment: That is definitely the main challenge. The other objectives tend to just happen in the course of trying to unlock more things in the game. But you'll need to put a lot of focus into exchanging cards efficiently to get the supply centers built.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The objective card says

> Build 3 **new** supply centers

So we have been playing where the upgrades have not counted towards our objective

Comment: That's the rule.

Comment: I'll check the box later, but I recall the improvement text specifically mentioning that any permanent depots don't count towards objectives

Comment: That's sad :(  guess we have to try harder to save the world

Comment: The first half of the game is viciously difficult. Just keep at it. Use the failed attempts to make strategic upgrades.